# security update Microsoft SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I want to apply the latest security update Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2016 (KB5001946) as of my understanding need to implement any security update ASAP but the  (KB5001946) is only the security fix which is only the language independent part. My question is can I install only this part or I need to also include the language dependent part KB 5001922 – SharePoint Server 2016 (language dependent).
but what I learned when new CU is released not to install and wait if any known bugs or issues and if the farm has a problem exist and specific CU will fix the issue (which in my case no issues or problems).
Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You should always apply the latest update for SharePoint Server 2016 and above. Yes, you must apply both KBs for a given month (non-locale and locale-specific patches).

[Updated Product Servicing Policy for SharePoint Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/product-servicing-policy/updated-product-servicing-policy-for-sharepoint-server-2016)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, please download them from official channels and install them after reading the introduction carefully and make sure your farm meet the installation requirements:

[SharePoint updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates)

There are similar related posts here:
[Windows 2019 OS updates on the SharePoint 2019 and SQL servers 2017](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/446781/windows-updates-on-the-sharepoint-2019-and-sql-ser.html)